# Change AddThis url dynamically with jQuery

Tags: jquery, addthis

I am trying to dynamically change the URL sent by addthis. When a user alters an element it updates a text area containing a custom url so they can return to that url and continue/view their work.

I am creating an addthis button like so(from their API docs):

```
var addthis_share = {url:"http://www.johndoe.com"}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tbx = document.getElementById("toolbox"),
    svcs = {email: 'Email', print: 'Print', facebook: 'Facebook', expanded: 'More'};
    for (var s in svcs) {
        tbx.innerHTML += '<a class="addthis_button_'+s+'">'+svcs[s]+'</a>';
    }
    addthis.toolbox("#toolbox");
});
```

Then when the url is updated I am trying to update the addthis share URL like so:

```
function updateURL(){
    ...get some variables here and generate a new url
    var newURL="http://the.url.i.want.to.share.com";
    $('#tagUrl').val(newURL);
    //addthis_share = {url:newURL}
    addthis_share = {url:newURL}
    addthis.toolbox("#toolbox");
}
```

The original buttons are getting generated and contain the correct url, but when the url update function executes the addthis share url is not getting updated.  How can I force it to update the addthis url?

Comment: You want to reload the page ? `window.location.reload()`

Comment: No...this url changes very frequently.

Comment: Hmm it's weird because your var `addthis_share` looks like to be global. You should try reloading the AddThis plugin or see if you can change the url in the DOM directly.

Comment: Thank you for your help: addthis.update('share', 'url', newURL); solved the problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you wants to change the addthis url after the html is loaded (in case of ajax or some user events),  please use the below hack . Addthis apis are broken as on
`[09/04/13 11:42:24 AM]` sunny jhunjhunwala:

```
addthis.update('share', 'url', 'http://www.sourcen.com'); 
addthis.url = "http://www.sourcen.com";                
addthis.toolbox(".addthis_toolbox");
```

http://www.sourcen.com ---> new url

Comment: hi can we change the discription in this way

Comment: Set "addthis:url" and "addthis:title" on each sharing toolbox you have on your page and call: addthis.toolbox(".addthis_toolbox");     Don't change the selector. See my example at http://jsfiddle.net/bs7g9rm8/

Answer (score 17):

It is as simple as this:

```
addthis.update('share', 'url', "http://www.example.com");
addthis.update('share', 'title', "Example Domain Title");
addthis.update('share', 'description', "Hello, I am a description");
```

Cheers,
Gary

Answer (score 1):

**To customized the button:**

```
<a class="addthis_button_compact" >
   <img src="./images/share.png" width="36" height="36" border="0" alt="Share" />
</a>
```

**Head Part:**

```
<meta property="og:title" content="YOUR TITLE" />
<meta property="og:description" content="YOUR DESCRIPTION" />
<meta property="og:image" content="YOUR IMAGE URL" />
```

**Body Part: In my case I am using php I set the body attributes like this.**

```
<body
      data-url="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>"
      data-title="<?php echo $info->record_info->brand; ?>"
      data-description="<?php echo $info->record_info->description; ?>"
      data-media="<?php echo ./uploads/logos/<?php echo $info->record_info->logo; ?>"
>
```

**To update content dynamically (JS Part):**

```
<script>
    addthis.update('share', 'url', $('body').data('url')); // will set the URL
    addthis.update('share', 'title', $('body').data('title')); // will set the title
    addthis.update('share', 'description', $('body').data('description')); // will set the description
    addthis.update('share', 'media', $('body').data('media')); // will set the image if you are sharing
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

AddThis provides addthis.update("share", "url", value) function (but it is a buggy function in IE8); try this one:

```
for(var i = 0; i < addthis.links.length; i++){
    addthis.links[i].share.url= "new url";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="share-obj" addthis:url="" addthis:title=""></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var shareConfig = {url: '', title: ''};

    addthis.button('#share-obj', {}, shareConfig);

    addthis.addEventListener('addthis.menu.open', function(event){
        if ( ! event.data.element.isSameNode($('#share-obj')[0])) {
            return;
        }

        event.data.share.title = shareConfig.title;
        event.data.share.url = shareConfig.url;
    });

    // in updateURL() or any other place during runtime...
    function updateURL() {
        shareConfig.url = 'http://different.url';
        shareConfig.title = 'Title changed dynamically...';
    }
</script>
```

I used a global variable `shareConfig` to keep track of the URL and title configuration. I have multiple addthis buttons in a webpage, each sharing different content. Therefore I have added a `isSameNode` to make sure I only update the button I want.

Although URL and title are changed dynamically, the `addthis:url` and `addthis:title` attributes must be present in the button (`<span>`), or else it won't work.

Comment: Where does `isSameNode` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Step-1: Preparing ajax content to be loaded with other HTML;

```
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox-CUSTOM" data-url="<?php my_dynamic_link(); ?>" data-title="<?php my_dynamic_title(); ?>">
    <a class="addthis_button_email" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_linkedin" style="cursor:pointer"></a>
</div>
```

Step-2: Preparing my fancybox ajax setup;

```
$('.popUpBtn').fancybox({
    //....other fancybox settings can go here...
    //....
    afterShow   : function(current, previous){
        //addthis.init();
        addthis.update('share', 'url', $('.fancybox-inner .addthis_sharing_toolbox-CUSTOM').data('url'));
        addthis.update('share', 'title', $('.fancybox-inner .addthis_sharing_toolbox-CUSTOM').data('title'));
        //addthis.update('share', 'description', "Hello, I am a description");
        addthis.toolbox('.addthis_sharing_toolbox-CUSTOM'); //-->Important: this selector should not be anything from the addthis settings page; We can choose any other names like normal selectors;
    }
});
```

The above lines inside the "afterShow()" function are important to keep a note;

Answer (score 0):

Just works for now

```
window.addthis.layers.refresh('new_url', 'new_title');
```

Another configs should be absent (like dom attributes) should be absent